# How can I apply a google font to an element based on it dynamically changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fonts, google-font-api

I loaded Google Fonts and pushed them into an array. I then replace the two placeholders with a randomly selected font and this is changed every time the button is pushed.

```
// Get a random font & apply it
function random() {
  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    var count = json.items.length,
        random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * count);
          document.getElementById("keyword").style.fontFamily =family[random];
          document.getElementById("keyword2").style.fontFamily =family[random];
          console.log(random)
    $.each(json.items, function (i, type) {
      if (i * 2 === random) {
        var family = type.family;
        $("#keyword").attr("placeholder", family);
        runFont(family);
      }
        random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * count);
      if (i * 2 === random) {
        var family = type.family;
        $("#keyword2").attr("placeholder", family);
        runFont(family);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This works for the most part, however a little buggy (they don't always change when the button is pushed or at the same time). My question is; how can I apply the selected font style to the input and placeholder?

full jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lsq97nu/2/

Comment: Your Random might collide (meaning it will be the same number twice or more) - This might be the issue in your case.
print the random output when you click, and see if the value's the same when the change doesn't occur.

Comment: @silicakes it seems that the value is different each time the change doesn't occur.